# Selected options automatically removed from search field on making ajax call in chosen js

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, json, jquery-chosen

I have dropdowns on which chosen js is applied and these dynamically fetch data from db based on input using ajax call, after selecting an option from dropdown when i enter another search term the dropdown list is updated but the selected item also vanishes, i want to keep the selected item even if the dropdown list gets updated after triggering .trigger("liszt:updated");

Comment: Please edit the question and share as much code as you can . https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask